# Ecto, Phoenix: How to update a model with an embeds_many declaration?

Tags: postgresql, elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I have two models, `Owner`and `Property`, where the schema for `Owner`has an [`embeds_many`](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Schema.html#embeds_many/3) declaration, like this:

```
defmodule MyApp.Owner do
  use MyApp.Web, :model

  alias MyApp.Property

  schema "owners" do
    field name, :string
    embeds_many :properties, Property
    timestamps()
  end

  @doc """
  Builds a changeset based on the `struct` and `params`.
  """
  def changeset(struct, params \\ %{}) do
    struct
    |> cast(params, [])
    |> validate_required([])
  end
end
```

and this:

```
defmodule MyApp.Property do
  use MyApp.Web, :model

  embedded_schema do
    field :name, :string
    field :value, :float, default: 0
  end

  def changeset(struct, params \\ %{}) do
    struct
    |> cast(params, [:name, :value])
    |> validate_required([:name])
  end
end
```

The [migration](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Migration.html) I'm using is:

```
defmodule MyApp.Repo.Migrations.CreateOwner do
  use Ecto.Migration

  def down do
    drop table(:owners)
  end

  def change do
    drop_if_exists table(:owners)
    create table(:owners) do
      add :name, :string
      add :properties, :map
      timestamps()
    end
  end
end
```

And a possible [seed](http://www.phoenixframework.org/docs/seeding-data) is:

```
alias MyApp.{Repo, Owner, Property}

Repo.insert!(%Owner{
  name: "John Doe",
  properties: [
    %Property{
      name: "Property A"
    },
    %Property{
      name: "Property B",
      value: 100000
    },
    %Property{
      name: "Property C",
      value: 200000
    }
  ]
})
```

Finally, my questions are: how can I update `John Doe`'s `Property C`'s value from   `200000`to `300000`? And if `John Doe` buys a `Property D`:

```
%Property{
  name: "Property D"
  value: 400000
}
```

How do I add that to his `properties` in the database? (I'm using [Postgres](https://www.postgresql.org/)).

Comment: Do you need something more efficient than fetching the whole list, modifying in Elixir, and saving?

Comment: @Dogbert not really :) . I just want to be able to do it, at first.

Comment: Just curious: how many properties can an owner have in your use case? Is there any reason you're using `embeds_many` instead of `has_many`?

Comment: @Dogbert It's because I don't need a separate `properties` collection, at least for the sake of this example. Maybe I could have used a better example (say, `Member` for an `Animal` model), but this is what I came up with :D.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simplest way would be to fetch the record, update the `properties`
list and save the changes:

```
owner = Repo.get!(Owner, 1)
properties = owner.properties

# update all properties with name "Property C"'s value to 400000
properties = for %Property{name: name} = property <- properties do
  if name == "Property C" do
    %{property | value: 400000}
  else
    property
  end
end

# add a property to the start
properties = [%Property{name: "Property D", value: 400000} | properties]

# or to the end
# properties = properties ++ [%Property{name: "Property D", value: 400000}]

# update
Owner.changeset(owner, %{properties: properties})
|> Repo.update!
```

You can do some operations (at least inserting a property) using the [JSON functions
provided by PostgreSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-json.html) using
`fragment` but I don't think you can search and conditionally update an item
of an array using them.